# Webpack 4 dev-server proxy does not recognize the wildcard

Tags: webpack, proxy, wildcard, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

My `webpack.config.js` file contains the following code inside the `module.exports`

```
devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    proxy: {
      '**': {
        'target': 'http://localhost:8888'
      }
    },
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "./templates"),
    watchContentBase: true
  }
```

It works fine whenever I change a file inside `/templates`, but changing any file under the subdirectories, such as `/templates/contacts/`, does not trigger a refresh on the page.

What am I missing?